# Should a ViewPager that creates ListFragments have each ListFragment call back to the ViewPager to handle list item clicks?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have an activity with a `ViewPager` as part of its layout that creates a series of `ListFragments` as its pages.  When the user clicks on a list item in one of those `ListFragments`, it takes them to a detail page that allows them to edit the details of that list item.

So in the `ListFragment`'s `onListItemClick()` method, I first check to see if it is in tablet (two-pane) mode, and if it is, I perform a fragment transaction that replaces the right-hand detail fragment with the detail fragment for the newly clicked list item.  If it is running on a normal phone, I just create a new activity that takes up the entire screen.  So basically, I currently have the `ListFragment` perform the new fragment/activity creation for when the user clicks on one of its items.

But instead, should the `ListFragment`'s `onListItemClick()` method call back to the `ViewPager` activity, and have the `ViewPager` activity contain this fragment/activity creation code?

The problem is that a `ViewPager` activity can only create fragments, so I cannot see how I can have each `ListFragment` call back to a custom `ListFragment` parent activity.  As far as I can tell, the `ListFragment` *must* have the `ViewPager` activity as its parent activity.  So if this is the case, is it good practice for the `ListFragment` to call back to its `ViewPager` parent activity to handle the fragment/activity creation for its list item clicks?

Comment: **"...must have the ViewPager as its parent activity."** : A `ViewPager` isn't an `Activity` - it's a `ViewGroup`. The `Activity` should have the `ViewPager` as part of its layout. A `ViewPager` shouldn't have the 'intelligence` to understand what `Fragments` it is adding / hosting but the `Activity` should. Create a 'callback' interface in each `Fragment` and have the `Activity` implement the interface and its methods.

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify that when I was mentioning "ViewPager", I was referring to the `Activity` that contains the `ViewPager`.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks for the comments.  I will create a callback interface in the `ListFragment` class that asks the `Activity` that contains the `ViewPager` to deal with the `Fragment` / `Activity` creation.

Comment: A golden rule with Fragments is they should never know what type of Activity they are attached to or how many (or what type) of other Fragments exist. If a Fragment can handle its own events (click events etc) internally then it can do so. If, on the other hand, an event will effect another Fragment (such as a multi-pane mode) then all communications should be via callbacks to the Activity. The parent Activity *knows* what Fragments it is using but all Fragments should be self-contained and never assume anything other than the fact they're attached to some sort of Activity.